# mule - default caching strategy not working

Tags: caching, mule, mule-studio

Using Mule default caching strategy - i understand that here the key is the input payload to the cache block.

Here even though I am sending multiple times the same payload, my logger is getting executed each time. My cache block does not seem to execute.

`<set-variable variableName="setEventSearchParameters" value="venueName=#[payload.Venue]&amp;eventDateLocal=#[payload.EventDate]T#[payload.EventTime]" doc:name="Set Event Search Parameters"/>
<set-payload value="#[flowVars['setEventSearchParameters']]" doc:name="Set Payload"/>
<ee:cache doc:name="Caching Event Information">
<https:outbound-endpoint exchange-pattern="request-response" method="GET" connector-ref="HttpsClientConnector" address="${autobulk.search.events.url}/?locale=en_US&#[payload]" contentType="application/json" doc:name="Get Event ID">
<logger message="New EventID" level="INFO" doc:name="Logger"/>
</ee:cache>`

Do I need to add any other property or bean? Further the above flow is within a for-each scope. Does this make it a consumable payload?
If it does, what is my alternate strategy?

Comment: Is the HTTPS inside Cache giving response back?

Answer (score 0):

With a configiration like that the cache key will be a SHA256 of the payload as per the [DefaultCachingStrategy](http://www.mulesoft.org/documentation/display/current/Cache+Scope#CacheScope-DefaultCachingStrategy).

Your configuration *should* work. Please place a logger like this right before the cache and share the results for different requests:

```
<logger message="-#[message.payload]-" level="ERROR" />
```

Answer (score 0):

what is your `#[payload.EventDate] and #[payload.EventTime]` ?

Is it constant or it is changing with time ??
If the payload is even slightly different, (ex:-EventTime is changed in seconds or milliseconds for every request) then you will not be getting from Cache

Check your input payload by putting a logger :-

```
<logger message="#[message.payload]-" level="INFO" />
```

Is the payload same every time or your payload getting different for  `#[payload.EventTime]` with seconds or milliseconds ?

If you **Event time** has **seconds** or **milliseconds** in it the payload will be different every time... Your **Cache** configuration seems correct for now